# Conflicting AutoSize and AutoWrap in TFlowPanel

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl, autosize

I am trying to use TFlowPanel component in the following manner:

1. Place on the main form `Form1` component `FlowPanel1: TFlowPanel`.
2. Set `Form1.Width = 400`, `FlowPanel1.Align = alTop`, `FlowPanel1.AutoSize = True`, `FlowPanel1.AutoWrap = True`.
3. Place on the `FlowPanel1` 5 SpeedButtons and set their `Width` to 64.
4. Compile and run.
5. Reduce width of the form (something about `Form1.Width = 200`).

For some reason, the speedbuttons do not automatically line up in two rows when user resizes the form. Although, they do line up in two rows when `AutoSize = False`, `AutoWrap = True`.
What is the reason for this behavior and how to solve it?

**Edit**: I've found "quick and dirty" solution. The following code is the event handler to the `TFlowPanel.OnResize` event:

```
procedure TForm1.FlowPanel1Resize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with FlowPanel1 do
  begin
    AutoSize := False;
    Realign;            // line up controls
    AutoSize := True;   // adjust TFlowPanel.Height
  end;
end;
```

However, I still wonder if there is a standard way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wasn't able to find the exact reason of such behavior in code, but basically you've challenged two sizing properties to fight, the [`AutoSize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.AutoSize) and [`Align`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Align). The problem is, I think, that when you resize a form, the control with [`AutoSize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.AutoSize) configured to True and [`Align`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Align) set to [`alTop`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TAlign) will first try to autosize the control and then align to top of its parent. What I can tell for sure, these two properties shouldn't be combined at least from their logical meaning.

What I would suggest to your workaround is turn off the autosize by default and in [`OnResize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.OnResize) event turn it temporary on and back to off to automatically adjust the height. So in code it would change simply to:

```
procedure TForm1.FlowPanel1Resize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // there's no Realign here, since the AlignControls request is called
  // at control resize, so here you have children already aligned, what
  // you then need is to request the control to autosize the height and
  // turn off the autosizing to the default, disabled state
  FlowPanel1.AutoSize := True;
  FlowPanel1.AutoSize := False;
end;
```

Comment: +1 for shorter and nicer code; Align and AutoSize are not combined by default.

Comment: `AutoSize` and `Align` go together well by default, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12412249/757830). Nice shortener though. +1

Answer (score 3):

> **tl,dr:** It's a bug in `TFlowPanel`.

Normally, the `AutoSize` and `Align` properties go together very well by default since this is taken care of already at `TControl` level, so I wondered why this happened. I noticed an overriden `AlignControls` method in `TFlowPanel` and thought to bypass it for testing purposes:

```
type
  TWinControlAccess = class(TWinControl);
  TAlignControls = procedure(Instance: TObject; AControl: TControl;
    var Rect: TRect);

  TFlowPanel = class(Vcl.ExtCtrls.TFlowPanel)
  protected
    procedure AlignControls(AControl: TControl; var Rect: TRect); override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...

procedure TFlowPanel.AlignControls(AControl: TControl; var Rect: TRect);
begin
  // Skip TCustomFlowPanel.AlignControls
  TAlignControls(@TWinControlAccess.AlignControls)(Self, AControl, Rect);
end;

procedure TForm1.FlowPanel1Resize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Do my own aligning of the last button
  if FlowPanel1.ClientWidth < Button5.BoundsRect.Right then
  begin
    Button5.Left := 1;
    Button5.Top := Button1.Height + 1;
  end
  else if FlowPanel1.ClientWidth > Button4.BoundsRect.Right + Button5.Width then
  begin
    Button5.Left := Button4.BoundsRect.Right;
    Button5.Top := 1;
  end;
end;
```

Now, this works as expected. So what's wrong with `TFlowPanel`'s implementation of `AlignControls`? It looks like the following snippet is the reason:

```
if AutoSize then
  Rect := TRect.Create(
    Rect.Left,
    Rect.Top,
    Rect.Left + (ExplicitWidth - (Width - (Rect.Right - Rect.Left))),
    Rect.Top + (ExplicitHeight - (Height - (Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top))));
```

When this part is commented out, the behaviour is as expected with `Align` set as well as not. Now, I would like to submit this to QC, but maybe I am overlooking some of its aspects. Please edit or comment when (and then why) this code indeed is needed.

Comment: +1, I've been suspecting the same, but wasn't sure. Still, I'll rather avoid to combine `AutoSize` with `Align` in my forms (maybe because of a logical reason and some bad experience from the past :-)

Comment: I've just tried TLabel component with `AutoSize=True`, `Align=alTop`, `WordWrap=True` and some long text in `Caption`. It seems that there is the same problem: resizing the form does not lead to adjusting height of the TLabel. Also, the same two-line shortener proposed by @TLama works fine.

Comment: `TLabel` has its own reintroduced `AutoSize` property which - I now dare to say - also has a buggy implementation. The same goes for `TStaticText`, etc... Thinking of it, I really don't get why these controls have reintroduced `AutoSize` properties or why they don't behave like implemented in `T(Win)Control`. This in comparison to `TToolBar` which doesn't rumble with an own `AutoSize` implementation but instead is satisfied with the one from `TControl` and auto sizes well because of it.

Comment: Thanks, I see now that TToolBar autosizes correctly. However, I cannot comment your answer about the bug in TFlowPanel as I've never delved into VCL source (maybe I should?). Probably I'll stay with simple workaround.